# system_call value is different each time when I use rdmsrl(MSR_LSTAR, system_call)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm writing a lkm to get `sys_call_table` address and I'm trying to get it by IDT (I have tested other methods and they work). The problem is that when I use `rdmsrl` to get register `MSR_LSTAR`, it's different each time.

I have tried function `rdmsrl` (`MSR_LSTAR`) and asm sentences in Ubuntu 18.04.1 with kernel 4.15.0-51.

```c
asm("rdmsr" : "=a" (low), "=d" (high) : "c" (IA32_LSTAR));
system_call = (void*)(((long)high<<32) | low);
printk(KERN_INFO "system_call: 0x%llx", system_call);
```

```c
rdmsrl(MSR_LSTAR, sct_off);
printk("sct_off: %016llx\n", sct_off);
```

The result is as follows:

```
system_call: 0xfffffe0000006000
system_call: 0xfffffe000008a000
system_call: 0xfffffe0000032000
```

Comment: Does it matter if you use `taskset` to make sure you invoke the system call from the same core every time?  IDK why different cores would have different MSR_LSTAR settings, but it's plausible.  Or maybe meltdown mitigation is something to do with this.

Comment: @Hadi: I'm not sure `[inline-assembly]` is a more useful tag *here* than `[assembly]`.  The inline asm isn't broken, and gives the same results as the Linux kernel's `rdmsrl` wrapper function (at least that's what I think the question is saying).  So the question is why Linux would modify the MSR over time, which is kind of a general assembly issue.  (Although really x86 covers that.)  But maybe `[osdev]`.  We could probably drop the `[intel]` tag, because I assume Linux does the same thing on AMD x86 CPUs, so it's not Intel-specific just x86-64 specific.

Comment: Searching Linux source for "LSTAR" (e.g. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=LSTAR&unscoped_q=MSR_LSTAR ) suggests that (unless virtualisation is involved - SVM or KVM or Xen) LSTAR isn't changed after boot.

Comment: I have tested it on ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.11.0-14-generic and 4.13.0-45-generic, the former shows correct result and the latter behaves the same as 4.15.0-51-generic. So I think there are some changes in kernel code

Comment: A longshot: Try adding `volatile` (ie `asm volatile`).  It's possible that (somehow) an optimization is (almost) occurring here.  Since the only input to the asm isn't changing, the asm might assume it can re-use the results from a previous calls, but the eax register might have been modified in the meantime?  It's a stretch, but easy to check.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Well spotted; the inline asm was wrong after all, contrary to my earlier comment.  So hard to catch every possible bug!  That's what builtins / intrinsics are for.  But the symptom would have been the value *not* changing when it should be changing, because of hoisting it out of a loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Say what?  He tried my suggestion and said it didn't help.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: In an earlier comment, I had said that the asm was fine.  If you're worried about detecting changes in this MSR within a single core, it's arguably not fine.  I was just saying how hard it is to reliably make claims about inline asm being bug-free.  Of course that bug wasn't the cause of the observed behaviour; with only one use per system call there's nothing for the compiler to optimize.  It won't invent a static variable to cache the result across calls even across cores.  (But I think it legally could!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `CONFIG_RETPOLINE=y` enabled? (check via cat `` /usr/src/`uname -r`/.config | grep RETPOLINE ``). If so, for CPUs where Kernel Page Table Isolation is enabled `MSR_LSTAR` holds the [trampoline per-cpu entry `SYSCALL64_entry_trampoline` instead of the standard `entry_SYSCALL_64`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c#L1370) for your kernel version.

Comment: Is the trampoline not just per-cpu?  So even using `taskset -c` to make the system call from the same core every time wouldn't work?  Your edit removed the "per-cpu" wording which I thought was a key part of the answer.  Now this answer doesn't fully explain why it would be different on different calls; it would be great if you could add back in a summary of what that would be the case.