# How can I check whether a kernel address belongs to the Linux kernel executable, and not just the core kernel text?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

Coming from the Windows world, I assume that `Vmlinuz` is equivalent to `ntoskrnl.exe`, and this is the kernel executable that gets mapped in Kernel memory.

Now I want to figure out whether an address inside kernel belongs to the kernel executable or not. Is using `core_kernel_text` the correct way of finding this out?
Because `core_kernel_text` doesn't return true for some of the addresses that clearly should belong to Linux kernel executable.

For example the `core_kernel_text` doesn't return true when i give it the syscall entry handler address which can be found with the following code:

```c
unsigned long system_call_entry;
rdmsrl(MSR_LSTAR, system_call_entry);
return (void *)system_call_entry;
```

And when I use this code snippet, the address of the syscall entry handler doesn't belong to the core kernel text or to any kernel module (using `get_module_from_addr`).

So how can an address for a handler that clearly belongs to Linux kernel executable such as syscall entry, don't belong to neither the core kernel or any kernel module? Then what does it belong to?
Which API do I need to use for these type of addresses that clearly belong to Linux kernel executable to assure me that the address indeed belongs to kernel?

I need such an API because I need to write a detection for malicious kernel modules that patch such handlers, and for now I need to make sure the address belongs to kernel, and not some third party kernel module or random kernel address. (Please do not discuss methods that can be used to bypass my detection, obviously it can be bypassed but that's another story)

The target kernel version is `4.15.0-112-generic`, and is Ubuntu 16.04 as a VMware guest.

Reproducible code as requested:

```c
typedef int(*core_kernel_text_t)(unsigned long addr);
core_kernel_text_t core_kernel_text_;
core_kernel_text_ = (core_kernel_text_t)kallsyms_lookup_name("core_kernel_text");
unsigned long system_call_entry;
rdmsrl(MSR_LSTAR, system_call_entry);
int isInsideCoreKernel = core_kernel_text_((unsigned long)system_call_entry);

printk("%d , 0x%pK ", isInsideCoreKernel, system_call_entry);
```

EDIT1: So in the `MSR_LSTAR` example that I gave above, it turns out that It's related to Kernel Page Table Isolation and `CONFIG_RETPOLINE=y` in config:

[system_call value is different each time when I use rdmsrl(MSR_LSTAR, system_call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542685/system-call-value-is-different-each-time-when-i-use-rdmsrlmsr-lstar-system-cal)

And that's why I am getting the address 0xfffffe0000006000 aka `SYSCALL64_entry_trampoline`, the same as the question above.
So now the question remains, why this  `SYSCALL64_entry_trampoline`  address doesn't belong to anything? It doesn't belong to any kernel module, and it doesn't belong to the core kernel, so which executable this address belongs to and how can I check that with an API similar to `core_kernel_text`? It seems like it belongs to `cpu_entry_area`, but what is that and how can I check if an address belongs to that?

Comment: Your code works for me on Linux v4.15 compiled with defconfig running under QEMU x86_64. After all, all `core_kernel_text` does is check that `addr` is between `_stext` and `_etext`. The entry point for 64-bit syscalls is `entry_SYSCALL_64`. What values do you see if you perform this check manually? Add the output of `sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep '_[se]text\|entry_SYSCALL_64$'` to your question if possible.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Are you sure that entry_syscall_64 is the same as the syscall entry handler that MSR_LSTAR points to? In my machine, MSR_LSTAR points to 0xfffffe0000006000, syscall table itself is at 0xffffffff9b400280, and  entry_SYSCALL_64 from kallsyms is 0xffffffff9b000020. Is the output of MSR_LSTAR and value of entry_SYSCALL_64 the same in your machine? (I also checked and the address of MSR_LSTAR indeed does have valid disassembly, which starts with swapgs instruction, so its not a invalid address)

Comment: Although I'm not using qemu, the target is a VMware guest (Ubuntu 16 x64)

Comment: @OneAndOnly yeah on the QEMU machine I tested `MSR_LSTAR` and `entry_SYSCALL_64` are the same. This is weird. Could you post your kernel config somewhere for me to look at? For example on https://pastebin.com.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Here you go: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/qurfUMmU   I also tried to grep for that fffffe0000006000 address in kallsyms, but no luck. Matter of fact even ffffe didn't return any result, all the addresses there start with ffffffff ! Also note that the target machine is the default ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @OneAndOnly [well, I'm all out of ideas at this point...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPDB2.png)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli  Me too! https://i.imgur.com/e3K9XGp.png  Although this could be because I'm using VMware and you're not, could be somehow related to virtualization? How does your syscall handler start? What is the dissasembly of starting instructions? does it start with swapgs?

Comment: Are you 100% confident that the code you posted is the same you are using? Modify the code snippet above so that it is a full module that can just be compiled as is. Also, remember that `%pK` prints an hashed version of an address, use `%px` for the real address or `%lx` for `unsigned long`. Other than these two things IDK what to say :')

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes I'm 100% confident, I am even inspecting the values with the debugger, so I'm not just relying on printks to see the values. Did you check to see what is the first instruction on the address of syscall entry handler for you?  Mine is this:  https://i.imgur.com/I84GH9X.png , So yours should be the same thing considering we are checking the same kernel version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250348/discussion-between-marco-bonelli-and-oneandonly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this "weird" address in `MSR_LSTAR` (IA32_LSTAR) because of [Kernel Page-Table Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_page-table_isolation) (KPTI), which mitigates [Meltdown](https://meltdownattack.com/). As [other existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569955/3889449)<sup>(1)</sup> you already found point out, the address you see is the one of a small trampoline ([`entry_SYSCALL_64_trampoline`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L166)) that is dynamically remapped at boot time by the kernel for each CPU, and thus does not have an address within the kernel text.

<sup>(1)</sup>By the way, the answer linked above wrongly states that the corresponding config option for KPTI is `CONFIG_RETPOLINE=y`. This is wrong, the "retpoline" is a mitigation for Spectre, not Meltdown. The config to enable KPTI is `CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION=y`.

You don't have many options. Either:

1. Tell VMWare to emulate a recent CPU that is not vulnerable to Meltdown.
2. Detect and implement support for the KPTI trampoline.

You can implement support for this by detecting whether the kernel supports KPTI (`CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION`), and if so check whether current CPU has KPTI enabled. The code at [`kernel/cpu/bugs.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/bugs.c#L257) that provides information for `/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/meltdown` shows how this can be detected:

```c
ssize_t cpu_show_meltdown(struct device *dev,
              struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    if (!boot_cpu_has_bug(X86_BUG_CPU_MELTDOWN))
        return sprintf(buf, "Not affected\n");
    if (boot_cpu_has(X86_FEATURE_PTI))
        return sprintf(buf, "Mitigation: PTI\n");
    return sprintf(buf, "Vulnerable\n");
}
```

The actual trampoline is set up at boot and its address is stored in each CPU's "entry area" for later use (e.g. [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c#L1370) when setting up IA32_LSTAR). [This answer on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476777/272806) explains the purpose of the cpu entry area and its relation to KPTI.

In your module you can do the following detection:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>     
#include <linux/module.h>     
#include <linux/init.h>       
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <asm/msr-index.h>
#include <asm/msr.h>
#include <asm/cpufeature.h>
#include <asm/cpu_entry_area.h>

// ...

typedef int(*core_kernel_text_t)(unsigned long addr);
core_kernel_text_t core_kernel_text_;

bool syscall_entry_64_ok(void)
{
    unsigned long entry;

    rdmsrl(MSR_LSTAR, entry);

    if (core_kernel_text_(entry))
        return true;

#ifdef CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION
    if (this_cpu_has(X86_FEATURE_PTI)) {
        int cpu = smp_processor_id();
        unsigned long trampoline = (unsigned long)get_cpu_entry_area(cpu)->entry_trampoline;

        if ((entry & PAGE_MASK) == trampoline)
            return true;
    }
#endif

    return false;
}

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    core_kernel_text_ = (core_kernel_text_t)kallsyms_lookup_name("core_kernel_text");
    if (!core_kernel_text_)
        return -EOPNOTSUPP;

    pr_info("syscall_entry_64_ok() -> %d\n", syscall_entry_64_ok());
    return 0;
}
```